# PHP-CGI Not working on CentOS 5?

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi, centos5

While trying to configure php-cgi on a CentOS 5 server running nginx, I run into this:

> [root@~~~~~~~ run]# /etc/init.d/php_cgi start
>
> Starting php-cgi: spawn-fcgi: child exited with: 255
>
> ```
>                                                       [FAILED]
> ```

I'm not 100% sure what's happening here, but no Google result returns anything regarding error code 255.

I was following [this guide][1] to set up php-cgi. What could the problem be?

Answer (score 1):

lighttpd and lighttpd-fastcgi both don't provide the binary that is supposed to be started with the script he provides. (/usr/bin/spawn-fcgi).

You'd better ask the guy who wrote the tutorial where he get /usr/bin/spawn-fcgi because on my server there is no way to install it with yum. He says "Install spawn-fcgi package using yum command" but it doesn't work.

Make sure you use the same repositories than him, with the same version of centos.

Comment: yum install spawn-fcgi worked for me though. =\

Comment: You may find you get better use out of PHP-FPM; PHP-FPM has been included in the PHP source code since 5.3.2. It negates the need for spawn-fcgi. I'm having a lot of success with it and Nginx.

Comment: Do note that FPM support is not enabled in RHEL's RPMs, so if you plan on having your distribution continue to provide security updates for your PHP version, stick with spawn-fcgi from EPEL. It works fine.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue, I deleted `/etc/sysconfig/spawn-fcgi`

It appears to be working now.

**Edit:**

Sorry, this is not the solution.

When installing php-cli it will install a php-fpm, not the original php-cli.

Remove all php packages `yum remove php*`and try to install the php53 binaries `yum install php53*`.